# strcmp and double equal relational operator not working in C

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

using the following program in C, the string comparison is not working:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char ch[]="ABC";
    printf("%d \n", strlen(ch));    // output 3
    printf("%d \n", strlen("ABC")); // output 3
    if(strcmp("ABC",ch)){
        printf("\n Matched");
    }else{
        printf("\n Not matched"); // this will be output
    }

    if("ABC" == ch){
        printf("\n Matched");
    }else{
        printf("\n Not matched"); // this will be output
    }
}//ends main
```

the output is:

```
3

3

 Not matched

 Not matched
```

Why the string is not matching?

Comment: Frankly, all of this should have been explained by any decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function returns a value of type `size_t`, for which the correct [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifier is `%zu`. Mismatching argument type and format specifier leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `"ABC" == ch` you compare two *pointers*, you don't compare what the pointers are pointing to. And these two pointers will never be equal.

And the [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function returns *zero* if the strings are equal. Zero is considered "false" in C, and all non-zero values are "true".

---

String literals in C are really arrays of (read-only) characters, including the terminator. As all arrays they decay to pointers to their first elements when they are used in most expressions.

Comment: BUT "ABC" == "ABC" return TRUE 
why ch == ch2 returns FALSE (here char ch[]="ABC" and char ch2[]="ABC") :

Comment: @mhk `ch` and `ch2` are different variables, and every variable has a distinct address, so they cannot be the same.  When you write `"ABC"` it may or may not refer to the same memory location as another instance of `"ABC"` (the compiler can choose)

Comment: @mhk The compiler is allowed to store only single copies of string literals. So both `"ABC"` are really the exact same string literal and thus comparing the pointers to them will be considered equal. If you have two different arrays, they are stored in different locations, and the pointers to them or their contents will be different.

Answer (score -1):

It would work if you change the double qoutes to single qoutes: "ABC" to 'ABC'